# Kotlin JSON deserialization with nested class discriminator

Tags: json, kotlin, serialization

I want to use a [class discriminator](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.serialization/blob/master/docs/json.md#class-discriminator-for-polymorphism) in Kotlin to get polymorphic deserialization of JSON messages. The problem is that the class discriminator in my messages is nested one level deep:

```json
{
  "header": {
    "message_type": "FooBar"
  }
  "data": {...}
}
```

The contents of `data` depend on `message_type`. If `message_type` were one level higher, this would be trivial by setting `@JsonClassDiscriminator("message_type")` on the base class and `@SerialName("FooBar")` on the subclass. But since it is nested it is unclear how to solve this without introducing a *ton* of boilerplate serialization code.

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest solution, but you can hack around this as such:

1. write your `@Serializable` object *as if* the discriminator is at the top level
2. when parsing, first use `decodeFromString<JsonElement>` to get a generic JSON object
3. use that object to move the discriminator to top-level
4. use `decodeFromJsonElement` to parse that

What step 3 looks like

```kotlin
// if json object has a message type in its header,
// return an object with that at top level so we can use it as a class discriminator
fun hoistDiscriminator(json: JsonElement): JsonElement {
    if (json is JsonObject) {
        val header = json["header"]
        if (header is JsonObject) {
            val discriminator = header["message_type"]
            if (discriminator is JsonPrimitive && discriminator.isString) {
                val map = json.toMutableMap()
                map["message_type"] = discriminator
                return JsonObject(map)
            }
        }
    }
    return json
}
```

and then the full parsing looks like this

```kotlin
json.decodeFromJsonElement(hoistDiscriminator(json.decodeFromString(response)))
```

There is a corner case in step 3: what if `message_type` is already defined at top-level? Handling that is left as an exercise to the reader.